# Error when using JMockit 0.999.11 with Maven 2.2 but able to work with junit and testng Options

Tags: jmockit

I am the getting the below error when I try to run my maven test or 
maven surefire test of a jmockit. But when i run through junit or 
testng it works fine.

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Unable to enqueue operation, pre-6.0 jvm.dll? at 
mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.loadAgentAndDetachFromThisVM(JDK6Ag­entLoader.java: 111) at
org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDir­ectoryTestSuite.java:111) 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to enqueue operation, pre-6.0 jvm.dll? 
at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.enqueue(Native Method) at 
sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.execute(WindowsVirtualMachine.java: 77) at 
sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(HotSpotVirtualMachi­ne.java: 53)

Above is the error that I am getting when executed with maven 2.2.

The enviornment I am using: 
Maven: 2.2.1 
JMockit: 0.999.11 
Added below in pom:

```
<plugin> 
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> 
<version>2.11</version> 
<configuration> 
<forkMode>once</forkMode> 
<argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}"/com/googlecode/ 
jmockit/jmockit/0.999.11/jmockit-0.999.11.jar</argLine> 
<useSystemClassloader>true</useSystemClassloader> 
</configuration> 
</plugin>
```

Java: IBM java 1.6 SR4

But when i add the javaagent path to junit or testng runtime vm args 
its running fine. But i tried adding even to maven test vm args but 
not working.

Please help me out on this.

Thanks in advance. 
-Srinath